# How does IEnumerable can be used for SQL withOut a provider?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

How does IEnumerable can be used for SQL withOut a provider?
I thought only IQueryable can be used to LINQ to SQL.

Im sory for my ignorent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework both require an underlying database provider.

You have to remember, though, that LINQ isn't a database specific technology. In its simplest form, there is LINQ to Objects that allows you to iterate over simple collections in .NET.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I can not find in your answer any connection to what I asked.

Comment: @StavAlfi it's the first sentence - IEnumerable **cannot** be used for SQL without a provider.